# How to invoke batch file from TFS build definition?

Tags: batch-file, tfs, msbuild

Once MSbuild is completed and respective files placed in drop folder, I would like to rename a file in the drop folder.

**Problem:**

1. Where to call the batch file in the TFS workflow build definition?
2. How to call the batch file passing the drop folder location as an argument to rename a file?

I have the following batch file which accepts the location to rename a particular file

`@echo off
set arg1=%1
move /Y set arg1+"xyz.exe" arg1+"xyz.STG.exe"`

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Set up an invoke process activity, to run your batch file
Place this activity in the finalize of Compile, Test and Publish, this will be the last thing to fire on the build server.

In your invoke process arguments pass in the droplocation

Comment: where and how to get the Drop folder path?

Comment: DropLocation should be a built in property, not got a tfs2012 instance in front of me, if not try under BuildDetails